Google Chrome Roles/Privileges API's are not accessible to non-super admin role user
I am trying to invoke below Google Chrome API's with non-super admin user
https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customer_id/roles
https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customer_id/roles/ALL/privileges

When I generate access token using the credentials with non-super admin role user and hit above API's I am getting below error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Both API's mentioned above works fine with super admin role user.
So, are Roles/Privileges API's can not be accessed with non-super admin user? Can you suggest me a solution if there is any to fetch Roles/privileges with non-super admin user?

Those URI seem to be from the admin SDK API [1] for those the answer is no, the adminSDK is meant to manage admin controlled resources[2] can be used by

super Admins
delegated admin

[1]https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/roles/get
[2]https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides

Thanks for the reply. Still have one doubt - Google provide several existing system roles(ex - service-admin) that are not super admin and are considered as a delegated admin. And the delegated admin also have no access to roles API - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/roles/get.
I have tried this already to call roles API with delegated admin and I got same error mentioned above - "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
Looks like its restricted only for the super admin because API call is successful and roles info is returned with super admin.
